# How should I filter log information created with Serilog.Sink.Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, serilog

I am using the [Serilog Elasticsearch Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-elasticsearch) to send logging information to an Elastic Cloud instance. My deployment has 4 separate applications that all send logging information. I would like to be able to easily filter log messages in Kibana according to the application which created them. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

***Here are the steps which can be helpful:-***
1.Login to Kibana.
2.At the top you may find "Add a Filter+" Option.Click on that.
3.Select the "Filter" Option as "source Name"
4.Select the "Operator" as "is"(as per your requirement from the drop down )
5.Enter your application name in the "Value" Field and Save.

This way you can filter based on your application .There are other options also available which you can use as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In Kibana, I can add a filter from the Discover page, but the data being provided by the Serilog Elasticsearch sink doesn't include a "source name" field.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my issue. The core problem was that the configuration of the Serilog sink didn't provide any context to allow me to filter in Elastic. I was able to add fields by using Serilog's built in [enrichment properties](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment).

In my case I was setting up logging through a json configuration file, so I was able to add the following content to the Serilog config in appsettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "Properties": {
        "ApplicationName": "application-name",
        "Environment" : "development"
    }
```

Then I could filter the objects in Kibana by fields.Application or fields.Environment to see distinct application logs.